# How do I monitor redistogo logs?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, redis, redistogo

I have a Rails app on Heroku using RedisToGo with gem redis. How do I do something similar to:

```
$ redis-cli monitor
```

but on RedisToGo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you mean that ?

```
redis-cli -h host.redistogo.com -p portnumber -a yourpassword monitor
```

If you are looking for a monitoring tool take a look at [**RedisLive**](https://github.com/nkrode/RedisLive) it requires some configuration and is self hosted but does the job.

On the contrary if you are looking for a full featued Redis GUI (real-time editor/client list/slowlog/data-viz, online monitoring, configuration, advanced terminal and so on...) you will want to give a try to [**Redsmin**](http://redsmin.com).

Disclaimer: I'm the founder of Redsmin.

Comment: hey man, great answer i appreciate it. i will try the cli for sure. and thanks for the disclaimer, i'd love to try redsmin and see what it has. i'll try to find you guys on twitter, i'm @kurtybot.

Comment: Done ! For other people interested just subscribe there http://invite.redsmin.com/ :)